# Delta Lake - Data skipping with z order and bloom filter index

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, z-order, bloom-filter

I am trying to optimize the transformations in my etl pipeline in Databricks using Data skipping for delta lake. I tried z-order and bloom filter index. However, I am unable to see what the impact is. Where can I see if it actually contributed to parquet files that were skipped during reading?
The screenshot below is from reading a delta table with bloom filter index on one column, and Z-order on one column as well. In the screenshot it shows *number of files pruned*, does this show the number of parquet files skipped when reading?

So my question is, what gives in general the best performance improvements? Z-ordering, bloom filter indexing, or a combination of both? And how can I check which combination of columns (that are Z-ordered or have a bloom filter index) gives the best performance improvements?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Z-Order and Bloom Filter Indexes can be run independently of each other.  In general:

- Z-Order is best with around 3-5 columns where you prioritize common filter columns and then join keys.
- Bloom Filters allow for faster point (needle in the haystack) queries so are handy for string columns like names and/or hashes.

Please start with this and if you'd like to dive deeper, check out [Tech Talk: Top Tuning Tips for Spark 3.0 and Delta Lake on Databricks](https://youtu.be/hcoMHnTcvmg) (*shameless plug here as I'm one of the speakers*)